# How to sort 2D array in Java based on two column's value

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a problem where I should sort out array of arrays and get sorted indexes of the array, I think some example will demonstrate my problem better than just describing by words. So,
I present several examples:

```
1-example:
n=3 
[1, 4] row=0
[2, 5]
[3, 6] row=2
output should be : 0 1 2 (explanation is below)
2-example:
n=5
[8, 9]  row=0
[4, 6]  row=1
[5, 11] row=2
[3, 4]  row=3
[4, 7]  row=4
[2, 6]  row=5
output should be : 3 5 1 4 0 2(explanation is below)
```

Sorting criteria mainly based on second column's value, first I should print the second column's smallest value's index, in 1-example it is 4 and it's index is 0  . If we encounter same values in second column as in 2-example (1 and 5 rows are same) then we should compare first columns corresponding values and print the smaller one's index first. Another more precise example of the problem:

```
n=3
[4, 6]  row=0
[1, 6]  row=1
[2, 6]  row=2
output should be : 1 2 0
```

EDIT: There is always 2 columns and n rows

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, if you want I can show you my try, but here I described problem partly, the actual problem is slightly different so the code

Comment: Every sorting algorithm would work as soon as you provide the right `compare` function.

Comment: @vishalgajera thank you for the answer

Comment: @Humoyun if you are satisfied with my answer, please up-vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is you complete solution try this,

```
public class TwoDimensitnArraySort {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ary[][] = {{8, 9},{4, 6},{5, 11},{3, 4},{4, 7},{2, 6}};

    ArrayList<TwoDArray> list = new ArrayList<TwoDArray>();

    for(int i = 0;i<ary.length;i++){
        int k = ary[i][0];
        int v = ary[i][1];
        list.add(new TwoDArray(k, v));
    }

    Collections.sort(list);
    int index = 0;
    for(TwoDArray element : list){
        for(int i = 0;i<ary.length;i++){
            if(element.getKey() == ary[i][0] && element.getValue() == ary[i][1]){
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
}

class TwoDArray implements Comparable<TwoDArray>{
    int key;
    int value;

    public TwoDArray(int key,int value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }


    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }



    public void setKey(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }



    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }



    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }



    public int compareTo(TwoDArray o) {
        if(o.getValue() >= this.getValue()){
            return -1;
        }else if (o.getValue() < this.getValue()){
            return 1;
        }
        if(o.getValue() == this.getValue()){
            if(o.getKey() >= this.getKey()){
                return -1;
            }else if (o.getKey() < this.getKey()){
                return 1;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    };
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.key + ":" + this.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime." You just gave that man a fish.

Comment: @JérômeBrunel what you mean ?

Comment: You threw the solution at him without giving any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, for this question, I think any sorting algorithm would work. You just need to specify your `compare` function to compare two elements.

For example, if you want to Bubble sort, in your case, with this algorithm (pseudocode taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation)):

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
  n = length(A)
  repeat 
    swapped = false
    for i = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
      if A[i-1] > A[i] then /* COMPARE LINE */
        swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
        swapped = true
      end if
    end for
    until not swapped
end procedure
```

You just need to replace the comparison on the line commented with `COMPARE LINE` with a `compare` function that would compare your objects just like you need (based on the second element and, if equal, the first element).

For example, replace this line by `if compare( A[i-1], A[i] ) then`.

To summarize, every sorting algorithm would work, as long as you provide the right `compare` function.

Comment: it is right, but I should also keep track of index not just values, main problem I am facing is after sorting I lose initial positions of indexes as they are sorted